# send log to another servers simultaneously

Tags: logs

I wanna send my application logs to other servers in other zones simultaneously that when I tail on all server's log file see the same log. Which technique suggest?

Comment: A centralised rsyslog server where all servers log are sent. When you login to rsyslog server and view the file you can see the aggregated logs of every server. There is a bit of setup you need to do though. It's not one line command to set everything up.

Comment: Tanks for reply, I found a solution with sshfs but it's not countinued on tail and should be commnad again to tail the log file.I am trying to work with rsyslog and set it up.